# Civilian requirements/restrictions for sending satellite into LEO

Tags: low-earth-orbit, law

What requirements and restrictions are there for a civilian organisation sending a satellite into LEO? (Apart from cost. I'm talking about any laws, agreements between nations etc)

This is in relation to a launch in the US, but with the payload coming from the UK or Europe.

Comment: I had to delete one answer for copyright violation and not being an own answer (all contents were copied off elsewhere), but here's a (working) link for reference that OP and answerers might find useful: Brent M. Timberlake, Essay, [_"TO BOLDLY GO WHERE ONLY A SELECT FEW HAVE GONE BEFORE: EXPLORING THE COMMERCIAL SPACE LAUNCH ACT AND THE LEGAL RISKS ASSOCIATED WITH REACHING FOR THE STARS"_](http://www.troutmansanders.com/files/Uploads/Documents/Timberlake-441-AS.pdf), University of Richmond School of Law; B.A., 2001 (PDF).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a general assumption that country of launch is responsible to enforce liability in case your launch fails and does damage.

In the US that is the FAA/AST where you need to get a launch license.  So being in orbit may or may not be directly regulated, the getting there part is.