# Can I launch a homemade rocket from the ground that can reach LEO?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, amateur-rocketry

If I had the time and the financial means to do so (and legal rights), could I design, build, launch, and deliver a small (very small)
payload to low Earth Orbit?
I think it would be awesome to put a small camera up in LEO and have it radio back a picture or two of the Earth before it de-orbits and burns up.

What would be the biggest hurdle to overcome?  My gut feeling tells me that the sheer amount of fuel I would need would be the biggest prohibittor (all legal issues aside :) ).

Comment: See [Is it possible to reach space using home-made rocket?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/10803/49), [Civilian requirements/restrictions for sending satellite into LEO](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/4882/49), [Am I allowed to send a rocket to LEO?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/6071/49),... What is actually your question? We can't guess what the biggest hurdle for you would be, but it's usually the money.

Comment: Fuel is cheap and easy. Look into amateur rocketry and the challenges they have. There are *many*.

Comment: @TildalWave I've changed the question to be more clear of what I"m looking for and why it is not a duplicate question.  Is it possible to launch my own rocket from the ground and deliver a payload to LEO.  Money aside, time aside, legal issues aside.  It is feasible.

Comment: FWIW, I voted to close as unclear what you're asking, because I don't think it's reasonable to expect that we'll know what problems of building and deploying an unknown system you'll find most challenging. That SE takes liberty to display my handle under a different close reason is not something I care to comment on.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you *could* design, build, launch and deliver a payload, given all your needs are met. I believe Elon Musk said that fuel only costs about .3% of the total cost. Granted, he's paying employees to do the work for him, but it should be relatively low cost compared to the rest of the components

The largest hurdle you will have to overcome is actually being able to launch it legally. See [Am I allowed to send a rocket to LEO?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6071/am-i-allowed-to-send-a-rocket-to-leo?lq=1)